# Oracle SQL - Complicated join: check if one of four values match

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am trying to get a new column in a table based on if an existing value exists in another table and I'm a bit blocked on how to solve this. I have the following two tables:

```
Table1
ID | Week | Year

Table2
ID | Week | Year | Counter
```

Table1 contains a set of available IDs in each given week. The counter in Table2 increases every time an action happens on an ID. If no action has happened, then the ID does not have an entry in Table2. Also, Table2 may contain IDs that are not available in Table1.

I now need to check for all IDs in Table1 if in the past four weeks any action has happened, in other words, if an entry for the given weeks in Table2 exists, and add this as Y/N to the results table. So if an ID in Table1 has week 47 associated with it, Table2 needs to be checked for the values 47,46,45 and 44 in week for the same ID.

```
Example

Table1
ID | Week | Year
-----------------
01 |   47 | 2017
02 |   47 | 2017

Table2
ID | Week | Year | Counter
----------------------------
01 |   45 | 2017 | 5
01 |   43 | 2017 | 2
02 |   43 | 2017 | 7

ResultsTable
ID | Week | Year | Active in past 4 weeks
------------------------------------------
01 |   47 | 2017 | Y
02 |   47 | 2017 | N
```

I am not sure how to proceed with this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What type of week number is this? Does the description for 'ww' or 'iw' formats apply? See here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924

Comment: From this list, it is IW

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
select  distinct a1.id,
        a1.week,
        a1.year,
        case
          when a2.id is not null
            then 'Y'
            else 'N'
        end active_in_past_4_weeks
from    table1 a1
left outer join table2 a2 on a1.id = a2.id and trunc(to_date(a1.year,'yyyy') + a1.week * 7,'IW') - 21 <= trunc(to_date(a2.year,'yyyy') + a2.week * 7,'IW');
```

Converting to a date for the join should help with the year changes.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to convert `WEEK/YEAR` column into a `DATE`. Preferably you should add them even as virtual column.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ISOWeekDate(WEEK INTEGER, YEAR INTEGER) RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC IS
    res DATE;
BEGIN
    IF WEEK > 53 OR WEEK < 1 THEN
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;      
    END IF;
    res := NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE( YEAR || '0104', 'YYYYMMDD' ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'MONDAY') + ( WEEK - 1 ) * 7;
    IF TO_CHAR(res, 'fmIYYY') = YEAR THEN
        RETURN res;
    ELSE
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
    END IF;
END ISOWeekDate;
```

Then the join will be simpler:

```
select distinct t1.ID ,t1.Week ,t1.Year,
    ISOWeekDate(t1.Week ,t1.Year),
    case when t2.id is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end active 
from table1 t1 
   left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
      and ISOWeekDate(t1.Week ,t1.Year) between ISOWeekDate(t2.Week, t2.Year)-3*7 and ISOWeekDate(t2.Week, t2.Year)
```